# Divisibility of adition combined with powers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I would like to ask the following (perhaps silly question) regarding divisibility.

Fix three positive integers $j, k, l$. My question is: is it true that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $m = m(n) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n | (j + k^m + l)$?

Comment: Consider what happens if $k = 1$.

Comment: You can combine $j$ and $l$ into one variable.

Comment: Even if you require the integers $j,k,l>1$ it is false.  Take $j=2=l$ and $k=3$.  Then $2$ does not divide $j+k^m+l$ for any $m$.

Comment: See [dscrete logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm)

Comment: Please don't change the question. Instead, ask a new question if you have another question.

Comment: As for your (rolled-back) edit the congruence $\, kx\equiv j\pmod{n}$ is solvable $\iff \gcd(k,n)\mid j.\ $ This is a basic result proved in many prior answers here and most all elementary number theory textbooks.

Comment: What does this notation mean $m=m(n)$?

Comment: It means that m depends on n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not always.  If $k=1$ it will often not be true and whether it is true will not depend on $m$.  If $n$ is even, $k$ is even, and $j+l$ is odd it will never be true.  If $k$ is a primitive root $\bmod n$ it will always be possible unless $j+l$ is a multiple of $n$.

Comment: I just checked the question and I wrote it thinking about the application I have in mind. I am editing the question. If possible, please have a look.